# Java Mail is not supporting UTF-8 Characters in Subject of the email

Tags: java

Here is my code of setting subject to the email:

```
  String bodyMessage="Dear Renavçilçleç Françoisç InCites&#8482;";
  String subject = "Your new InCites&#8482; subscription";

  Properties _sessionProperties = new Properties();
  _sessionProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  _sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", "hostname");
  _sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

  Session session = Session.getInstance(_sessionProperties, null);

  MimeMessage mimemsg = new MimeMessage(session);
  mimemsg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "xxx@gmail.com");
  mimemsg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

  // Create a multi-part message
  MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  // Set the subType
  multipart.setSubType("alternative");
  BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();

  part.setContent(bodyMessage, "charset=UTF-8");

  // Set the emailBody and emailType to MIME BodyPart
  part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
      bodyMessage, "text/html;")));

  // Add the MIME BodyPart to MIME multiPart
  multipart.addBodyPart(part);

  // Put parts in message
  mimemsg.setContent(multipart);

  // Send message
  Transport.send(mimemsg);
```

But still in email subject it still shows as `"Your new InCites&#8482; subscription"`

Comment: So... is the problem that the email client is showing you exactly what you want to see?

Comment: I am trying to set UTF-8 character support in subject of the email. But still I cant able to do that in subject of the email

Comment: @Sentil: How to support UTf-8 characters in the Subject of the email using MimeMessage or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: The problem is I am setting UTF code for 'TM' symbol. In the client email body it decodes fine into that symbol but in the subject it shows the code instead of decoding into 'TM' symbol.

Comment: @Kalyan, You are using HTML encoding to encode a character and your mail client is displayed the encoded data. Beats me on why you havent attempted using the character as is.

Comment: It is the Unicode for the symbol 'TM' (i.e. Trade Mark Symbol)

Comment: No it isn't. U+2122 is the Unicode codepoint for `™`. What you've put is a bunch of ASCII characters.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Can u send me the code to include trade mark symbol in the subject line of the email

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Please refer the code. In the body of the email the TradeMark symbol code is decoded perfectly but in the subject it reflects as code itself

Comment: @Kalyan, I'll be blunt. You need to understand how the mail client performs decoding of mail messages. The body is likely to displayed using a HTML renderer and that's why HTML encoding works in the body. It will not be the same for the subject, and that us why several people have recommended using the UTF-8 character (in the manner that it can be represented in Java source code). Using a HTML encoded character in such a place will not get you anywhere because HTML encoding employs the use of ASCII.

Comment: Vineet Reynolds : Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The subject you mention here consists completely of ASCII characters. This includes the funny special characters `&#8482;`. If you want it to be Unicode, just use Unicode and not the HTML-escaping. Mails don't have anything to do with HTML.

```
mimemsg.setSubject("Your new InCites\u2122 subscription", "UTF-8");
```

This should encode the subject as something like `=?UTF-8?Q?Your...subscription?=`, as specified in [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).

The complete example code:

```
package so4406538;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSubject("Your new InCites\u2122 subscription", "UTF-8");
    message.setContent("hello", "text/plain");
    message.writeTo(System.out);
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Message-ID: <7888229.0.1291967222281.JavaMail.roland@bacc>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Your_new_InCites=E2=84=A2_subscription?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

hello
```

You can see that the subject header is encoded, and this is necessary and correct.

[**Update:** I fixed the Unicode escape sequence, as indicated in one of my comments.]

Comment: After trying the above code the subject in emails changes to "Your new InCites? subscription".But I am expecting symbol 'TM' (i.e. Trade Mark Symbol) after InCites.

Comment: I know. The `?` is only displayed in the Eclipse console. If you configure the console to show UTF-8 it will be there. It's under "Run -> Run configurations -> Common -> Console Encoding".

Comment: I am looking the output in the Microsoft outlook client. And my email body is not of type "text/plain" it is "text/html"

Comment: That still means that the email subject has nothing to do with HTML. By saying that the body is `text/html`, you don't influence the subject in any way. Just pass the (tm) symbol as an ordinary character (not HTML-encoded), and it will work.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. The correct conversion of `&#8482;` to a Unicode escape sequence in Java is `\u2122`, not `\u8482`.

Comment: I don't have the function MimeMessage.setSubject(String,String); what version of the mail jar is that?